# Query String Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, how do I add some data to the query string?

Basically I want to add the window.screen.height and window.screen.width info to the query string so that I can then email it with the other login info.

Alternatively, how would I populate a couple of hidden fields with the same data, a form is being submitted so I could pick it up from there?

Thanks, R.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add the querystring? to the form action attribute or a link somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the latter option would be easier to implement. For example, if you have the hidden fields like this:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="screenheight" id="screenheight" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="screenwidth" id="screenwidth" value="" />
...
```

Then the JavaScript would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('screenheight').value = window.screen.height;
document.getElementById('screenwidth').value = window.screen.width;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did go with the hidden fields and javascript combo and it worked out really well.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy that worked out for you. Please mark as answer if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [jquery.query.js](http://code.google.com/p/multi-doc/source/browse/trunk/static/jquery-query.js?spec=svn19&r=19) to play with querystring.

Answer (score 0):

for hidden fields, give each field an ID then do this

`$("#fieldID").attr("value") = someVal`ue;

UPDATE: Sorry, I saw Query and that made me think jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is nice, but it will require jQuery :).

Comment: still not valid as you would need quotes around #fieldID

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add it to the location in a library agnostic manner, you could do the following:

```
var query = window.location.search;
var sep = "?";
if (query) {
   sep = "&";
}
window.location = window.location + sep + "h=" + 
    window.screen.height + "&w=" + window.screen.width;
```

This of course assumes that you don't have w or h parameters in the query string already.